# How to insert variables into text when storing content in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm using the code below to insert content into a page. I need to insert some variables in the text to generate some dynamic values and am unsure how to do this. Can someone tell me what I'd need to change?

Here's a slimmed down example of how I'm storing the data in my JS:

```
var fruit = {
    'apples': {
        'goldenDelicious' : {
            color: 'yellow',
            sale: 'A sale of $XXXXX (need to insert a number in here). Be sure to buy some before they are all gone!',
            link: {
                linkText: ('This company sells this for $XXXXX (eed to insert a price here). Click here to visit their site.'),
                url: 'I NEED TO INSERT THE URL HERE'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how I'm calling it: (it's more dynamic than this, but you get the idea)

```
var fruitType = 'apples';
var fruitVariety = 'goldenDelicious';

fruit[fruitType][fruitVariety], function () {
    // do something
});
```

So what I'd like is to be able to insert values like a price, sale, and URL into the object.

Comment: You should keep your data as they are, and make the conversion when rendering them(I guess in HTML). This is exactly what a javascript template engine does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. If you're going to be doing a lot of this type of replacement, you'll probably want to look at a templating engine. I've been using [Trimpath](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates), and am happy with it.

If you don't want to get that fancy yet, put your own placeholder tokens in the string and then replace them.

```
var fruit = {
    'apples': {
        'goldenDelicious' : {
            color: 'yellow',
            sale: 'A sale of PLACEHOLDER_1. Be sure to buy some before they are all gone!',
            link: {
                linkText: ('This company sells this for PLACEHOLDER_2. Click here to visit their site.'),
                url: 'I NEED TO INSERT THE URL HERE'
            }
        }
    }
}

fruit.apples.goldenDelicious.sale = fruit.apples.goldenDelicious.sale.replace("PLACEHOLDER_1", "the real value");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It doesn't seem to want to work with using the dot notation -- it will just work with using brackets. Any ideas why? Do I need to go and define goldenDelicious and sale? I tried putting them in quotes but that didn't help either.